# A positive-sounding word synonymous to 'dismantling'

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a word which means 'breaking down some concept and building it again'. To elaborate, suppose I have learnt a concept, but have missed a lot of intricate details in it. So, I want to start from the beginning. I want to dismantle that concept, but not in the sense of destroying or discarding it, or dismantling it because the concept itself is wrong. I want to break it down, and start building it from the basics. Is there a word for this? The Thesaurus suggested words like annihilate, demolish, destroy, tear down, etc. All these words have a negative-sound. I want a word that means the same in a positive sense. As an example, '___-ing Algebra' would be a good title for a book that teaches Algebra from the very basics and in a greater detail than usual.

Comment: The common phrasing is ***deconstructing***; it’s used widely in PoMo and its descendent disciplines. There, it is neutral-to-positive (because deconstruction is considered critical work).

Comment: Please show us what your thesaurus searches found unacceptable and why.

Comment: @DanBron I can't figure out what PoMo is, and I really tried. I'm guessing not the language of the Pomo indians, nor a slang term for postmodern architecture.

Comment: @PhilSweet You hit it with *postmodernism*. Just not architecture. Academia, lit crit, social sciences, etc.

Comment: @tchrist Thesaurus suggested words like annihilate, demolish, destroy, tear down, etc. They all have a negative-sound. What I want is a word which can be used in a positive sense.

Comment: @DanBron In which case I'm more familiar with it as not-a-good-thing. "They could rip it down and replace it with some **Po-Monstrosity**, but it'd still be saddled with a mobile tower, be tenantless and quite rapidly reach dereliction." [here](https://theworstofperth.com/2017/01/24/upcycle/
)

Comment: @Tejas Ok thanks, good enough. Please edit your question to include your comment about what you found in the saurus but didn't like.

Comment: @PhilSweet To be clear, I’m not fan of PoMo (though I think the vulnerabilities in Modernism it was founded to critique are real and troublesome). What my first comment was intended to convey was, *within the discipline of PoMo*, the act of “deconstructing” is central and vital. There, the act can be described neutrally, as an operation, a matter of fact, or it can have positive shades, as it exposes the flawed or problematic premises hidden in a text (good deconstruction is good work in PoMo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [revisit](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revisit) (Collins)

> to re-examine (a topic or theme) after an interval, with a view to making a fresh appraisal

or

[Develop](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/develop)/redevelop (Collins)

> 8: If you develop a skill, quality, or relationship, or if it develops, it becomes better or stronger.
> 12: If you develop an idea, theory, story, or theme, or if it develops, it gradually becomes more detailed, advanced, or complex.

As an example:

> '**Algebra Revisited**' would be a good title for a book that teaches Algebra from the very basics and in a greater detail than usual.
>
> '**Redeveloping Algebra**' would be a good title for a book that teaches Algebra from the very basics and in a greater detail than usual.

Answer (score 2):

If you seek to convey the idea you are not simply tearing something apart ("[deconstructing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconstruction)") but also contributing by bringing "it" back yet in a different shape, you may consider these terms: **reconstruct, refashion, and recast**.

They are not as widely used as "deconstruct" in literary criticism, but they transmit a more collaborative approach.

Mind the context, however. "Deconstructing's" high currency in some genres relates to the aversion in [PoMo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodern_literature)(Postmodern literature) to "construct" things. Building a case sets you up for "deconstruction."

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if it will suit your sentence, but you can use the word "restoration"